# Explanation of assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, push, bootloader

I have started to learn assembly. I came across these lines.

```
;*************************************************;
; Second Stage Loader Entry Point
;************************************************;

main:
   cli  ; clear interrupts
   push cs ; Insure DS=CS
   pop ds
```

Here on second line of code, the code segment is push to the stack(I think this). I have seen it in many codes. Why we should do this and how it ensures DS =CS? On third line DS is pop out of stack(I think this). Why it is done? It is pop out of stack means it was push to stack before. There is no code for that. Can anybody explain all this to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the `push cs` that ensures this, it's the `push cs; pop ds;` combination that does.

The first instruction copies the current value of `cs` onto the stack, and the second pulls that value off the stack and puts it into the `ds` register.

---

In response to your request for more information, let's start with the following stack and registers:

```
stack=[1,2,3], cs=7, ds=6
```

After `push cs`, which pushes the value of the `cs` register onto the stack:

```
stack=[1,2,3,7], cs=7, ds=6
```

After `pop ds`, which pops a value off the stack and put it into the `ds` register:

```
stack=[1,2,3], cs=7, ds=7
```

And that's basically it.

---

I can't recall of the top of my head whether it was possible to transfer between segment registers with a `mov` instruction (I don't think it was, but I may be wrong, and this would necessitate the push/pop sequence). This [link](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/m.html#MOV) would seem  to confirm that: there is no `mov` option with a segment register as both source *and* destination.

But even if it were, assembler coders often chose more suitable instructions, either for speed or compact code (or both), things like using `xor ax, ax` instead of `mov ax, 0` for example.

Comment: Can you explain this to me in detail. How push ds ; pop cs ensures ds = cs?

Comment: You can use `MOV` on reg,reg. See: http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/m.html#MOV

Comment: Yes, but cs/ds aren't regular registers. I think on that table you link to, they're `segreg` values and there's no segreg/segreg option.

Comment: Yep, iirc it's bad practice to mov reg,reg anyways, because it's not supported for all registers.

Answer (score 4):

`cs` and `ds` are just registers, pretty much like placeholders/variables, for more [information about registers read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register). On the second line you are saying `push cs` this means that you put the content of `cs` onto the stack and on the following line you `pop` it back into `ds`.

So what just happened was that you copied `cs` to `ds`.

[`push`](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/p.html#PUSH) is an instruction that says "put this on top of the stack"

[`pop`](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/p.html#POP) is an instruction that says "take the top value from the stack"

Once you do a `pop` the value is no longer stored on the stack.

Comment: Possibly because cs and ds are registers rather than memory locations, who knows?

Comment: Not me, but CS and DS are not memory adresses, they are registers.

Comment: This is one of the better explanations. He understood what I wanted to ask explained in simple words. May be cs ds can be registers, but I understood the concept of pop and push.

Comment: Oh right, it's the 16 bit reprecentations of ecx/edx.. Dooh.. :)

Comment: It may well be one of the better explanations, it's just a pity it's _wrong_ :-) I'd be happy to upvote if he'd just get rid of that glaring error.

Comment: NO, CS is NOT CX.  CS is a segment register, like DS, ES, FS and more. They were used to store the memory segment (you know 2471:2A4E). CS was the code segment, DS the data segment, ES the extra segment. And with FS and GS it got freaky.

Comment: @Gamecat, thanks you learn something new every day. Anyways it's changed to "registers" instead of memory adresses.

Comment: It would be interesting to add to the answer the reason why it's not simply moved.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, have a look at my answer for some of the dirty details.

Answer (score 1):

The 'push this register onto stack, pop stack to this register' can sometimes be done with MOV instructions, such as MOV ax,dx. But some register-to-register MOV instructions aren't available in the instruction set, and IIRC MOV ds,cs isn't available. That could be the reason for putting it in memory (well, cache, really) and reading it back.

Answer (score 0):

By pushing the value of CS to the stack, and popping it into DS, you ensure that DS has the same value as CS.

I haven't programmed in assembler for a while, but I thought there was no direct way to move from one segment register into another.

You can see the stack as a pile of data. You push something on top and it stays there until you pop it of\ the pile. In that way you can use the stack to exchange data. But most of the time you use it to save data so you can use the registers for other purposes and restore the content later.

This happens when you execute the code.

1) initial situation

```
CS has value X
DS has value Y
Stack has ....
```

2) push CS

```
CS has value X
DS has value Y
Stack has ...., X
```

3) pop DS

```
CS has value X
DS has value X
Stack has ....
```

But what are segment registers.
In the old days, 8086 had 16 bit address registers but a 20 bit addressspace. So they used the segment registers to combine both to a 20 bit space by multiplying the segment register by 16, and add the memory location. To save space, we had near pointers (without segment to jump within the segment) and far pointers (with segment).

With the introduction to 80286 protected mode, the segment registers were reused as segment descriptors. They pointed to a memory location that gave enough information to get to the real space. But now we have linear address spaces (virtually mapped on the real memory).

Comment: I think the terminology is a little off. IIRC CS,DS,... are selector registers wich point to segment descriptors which are structures in memory.

Comment: @ninjalj, originally they where segment registers. The name still stands, the function has changed.

Comment: I was referring to this part: «the segment registers were reused as segment descriptors.» Segment descriptors should be selector registers there.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the comment written, `push cs` and then `pop ds` ensures that `ds=cs?`. `push cs` puts the value of cs on the top of the stack, and then `pop ds` removes the value from the stack and stores it in `ds`.